# How much WCF efficient to get real time data?

Tags: c#, wcf

Suppose I have a thousand of hardware device(about 20,000) which send the data in real time. I have to capture this data and send all data to database and also show information in application.For this I am thinking to develop a WCF service which poll all the devices and get the data from devices and store in database.

So my question is "Is WCF efficient to do this or I should follow another approach "

Comment: Are the 20,000 devices running Windows?

Comment: no,they are not connected to windows,they are connected from Ethernet

Comment: @wikky - I mean, are they running the Windows Operating System? Or, at least, are they capable of running the .NET Framework?

Comment: Yeah they are capable.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking to develop a WCF service which poll all the devices

A WCF service cannot "poll". A consumer *can* poll, which is to say it can call a service over and over again, however there is no polling pattern built into WCF client channel. So any polling behavior will need to be programmed.

> So my question is "Is WCF efficient to do this or I should follow
>   another approach "

What I suspect is that you actually want your devices to call the service and pass data, so what you are actually asking is *Can a WCF service handle a high volume of calls?*, to which the answer is Yes.

However, in order to get the best scalability you should expose a per-call service, and do this over netTcpBinding (basically sockets), which uses optimised encoding and is therefore higher performance.

This would only be available to a consumer running the WCF client stack. If WCF is not available on your devices then the next best option is probably an HTTP endpoint over webHttpBinding, which provides the best interoperability.

> Can you please suggest some other technology?

Well, if you are happy using http on your devices you should look at [nancyfx](http://nancyfx.org/) for hosting your service - it's a really nice, lightweight http container for .net.

Comment: Yeah, polling is implement by coding .So according to answer WCF would be right choice?

Comment: @vikky It's a choice which would work. I don't know if it's *the* correct choice....

Comment: Thank you for your response,Can you please suggest some other technology?